# I used to solve code golf puzzles like you, but then I took an arrow in the knee

Tags: code-golf, path-finding

Getting hit in the knee with arrows seems to be the [injury of choice](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vncIBREXCwU) right now. As such, I propose the following golf challenge.

You have an adventurer that looks like this:

```
  O
 /|\
/ | \
  |
  |
 / \
/   \
```

Given a text file that contains one bow (drawn as a `}` symbol), a set of walls (drawn as `#` symbols) and one adventurer, write the smallest code that calculates the angle and initial velocity at which you should fire an arrow in order to hit him in the knee.

Assume the following:

- Each character in the file is 0.5 x 0.5 meters.
- The arrow is fired from the center of the `}`, i.e. an offset of `0.25m, 0.25m`
- Gravity is `10ms^-2`
- Arrow weighs `0.1kg`
- Arrow is a point, i.e. collisions only occur when the arrow's coordinate enters one of the blocks.
- Maximum initial velocity is `50m/s`
- Angle may be between 0 (straight up) and 180 (straight down)
- Hitting any part of the adventurer's leg is considered a hit to the knee.
- A wall (`#` character) takes up one entire 0.5m x 0.5m block.
- The arrow can travel over the "top" of the file, but there's nothing to stop the input from starting with a ceiling of `#` characters.
- You can't penetrate walls with arrows.
- Hitting any other part of the adventurer is not allowed!
- You should display an error if hitting him in the knee is impossible.

Example input:

```
                                 #                        
}                                                     O   
                        #                            /|\  
                                                    / | \ 
            #                                         |   
                            #                         |   
                                                     / \  
                                                    /   \
```

Feel free to ask questions if you need to :)

Comment: Can the arrow travel "over" the area depicted by the text file?

Comment: How many people do you know who are over 3m tall? :P

Comment: @JB - Yes, but there's nothing to stop the input starting with a big line of `#############`...

Comment: @PeterTaylor - Everyone knows that people in RPG games are disproportionately huge ;)

Comment: @Polynomial fair enough. Thanks for answering :)

Comment: Will the adventurer always be on the bottom row? And do arms and legs fill the entire block too? (Or at least the entire diagonal, which is equivalent for practical purposes?)

Comment: Is there an e.g. rectangular envelope around the adventurer that's free of walls?

Comment: @PeterTaylor - They aren't always on the bottom, no. For simplicity you could say that each leg takes up the whole block, but in general I would prefer it if you assumed the leg was a line between opposite sides.

Comment: @leftaroundabout - No. They could be entirely encased in walls. In that case you would hit the final assumption - "You should display an error if hitting him in the knee is impossible."

Comment: The weight of the arrow is redundant, surely ?

Comment: @PaulR - Hehe, I put it in there as a tease. Wondered how long it would be until someone noticed it was irrelevant :P

Comment: I need to make a language where this is 9 bytes-- `Dovahkiin`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Python, 599 chars

```
import os,sys
from math import*
I=os.read(0,999)
O=[]
h=v=0
for i in I:
 if'#'==i:O+=[(h,v,h+1,v+1),(h+1,v,h,v+1)]
 if'O'==i:O+=[(h,v+1,h-2,v+3)];T=(h,v+5,h-2,v+7)
 if'}'==i:e=h+.5;c=v+.5
 h+=1
 if'\n'==i:v+=1;h=0

def X(K,L):
 A,B,C=K;p=L[0];q=L[2]-p;r=L[1];s=L[3]-r;A,B,C=A*q*q,2*A*p*q+B*q-s,A*p*p+B*p+C-r;d=B*B-4*A*C
 return 0 if d<0 else any(0<x<1 for x in[(sqrt(d)-B)/2/A,(-sqrt(d)-B)/2/A])

R=range(1,999)
for v in R:
 for z in R:
  z*=pi/999;d=v*sin(z)/10;b=-v*cos(z)/10
  K=20/d/d,b/d-40*e/d/d,c+20*e*e/d/d-b*e/d
  if X(K,T)and not any(X(K,x)for x in O):print v/2,z;sys.exit(0)
print'ERROR'
```

The `X(K,L)` routine takes a parabola `K=(a,b,c)` representing *y=ax^2+bx+c* and a line segment `L=(a,b,c,d)` representing the segment between *(a,b)* and *(c,d)*.  Both obstacles (`O`) and the target (`T`) are repesented as line segments.  All distances are scaled by a factor of 2.

The example input gives the following trajectory (by default, the minimum velocity one):

```
  --                             #          --            
--                                            -       O   
                        #                      -     /|\  
                                                -   / | \ 
            #                                    -    |   
                            #                     -   |   
                                                   - / \  
                                                    -   \
```

you can reverse `R` to get the maximum velocity path:

```
                                 #                        
-------------                                         O   
             -----------#                            /|\  
                        --------                    / | \ 
            #                   -------               |   
                            #          -----          |   
                                            -----    / \  
                                                 -----  \
```

Comment: Good work. Only complaint is that the input size limit is 999 bytes. It could quite easily be more, considering the potential size of these ASCII drawings. 9999 would be more sensible, at the cost of only 1 character. (though at that point you might as well do `8**5` to get 64kB)

Comment: Pretty sure you could then save that one character by assigning `w=v+1` and replacing the 3 instances of `v+1` with `w`. I don't code much Python though, so I may be wrong.